# Using meteor functionality in external frameworks

Tags: meteor, tizen-web-app

Is there a recommended way where you can use the full meteor functionality like collections, calls, sync, reactivity in other frameworks like Tizen Web?

Blaze at least seems to be useable: https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/using-blaze-templates-tizen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despite the recommendation on the tizen website the [asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) component is quite simple to include and provides much more functionality for connecting meteor applications from standalone apps or websites.